# Ways to choose $n$ out of $2n$ balls with three distinct colors

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I am working on a problem where I need to know how many ways there are to choose n out of 2n balls with three distinct colors, as a function of the numbers of balls of each color (The order does not matter). I already found a few answers on here that come close to what I need, namely [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378943/ways-of-choosing-n-objects-out-of-3n-objects) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641433/number-of-ways-to-partition-40-balls-with-4-colors-into-4-baskets), but I do not understand enough of the solutions so that I can make it work for my problem. Also, the multivariate hypergeometric distribution seems related, but I have not managed to extract the information I need from any of the texts. Can you help?

Edit: Another way to phrase it would be: How do I distribute the 2n balls evenly between two *distinct* boxes.

Comment: In the edit, are the $2n$ balls all distinct?

Comment: No, the same balls as above. Only distinct by color, but indistinguishable among their own color.

Comment: I see, and the colours are randomly distributed like $r+g+b=2n$ wehere $r,g,b\ge 1$ stands for the numer of red, green and blue balls?

Comment: yeah, but 0 is allowed too as an edge case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there are $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$ balls of the three colors. Consider the polynomial
$$g(x):=(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{m_1})(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{m_2})(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{m_3})\ .$$
[The $g$ is for *generating function*.] If you expand the right hand side here you obtain for any choice of numbers $k_i\in[0\,..m_i]$ a term
$$x^{k_1}\,x^{k_2}\, x^{k_3}$$
(with coefficient $1$). Collecting these terms according to total degree gives us the "usual" presentation of $g(x)$. The coefficient of $x^n$ in this presentation is exactly equal to the number of admissible  triples $(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ satisfying $k_1+k_2+k_3=n$. Concerning your problem we therefore have to find this "usual" presentation of $g(x)$. We can write
$$\eqalign{g(x)&={1-x^{m_1+1}\over 1-x}\>{1-x^{m_2+1}\over 1-x}\>{1-x^{m_3+1}\over 1-x}\cr  &=
(1-x^{m_1+1})(1-x^{m_2+1})(1-x^{m_3+1})\sum_{j=0}^\infty{j+2\choose 2} x^j\ .\cr}$$
Now you have to collect the eight terms (coming from the product to the left of $\Sigma$) having the total degree $n$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! What is the concept behind this approach? Why does this work?
Edit: Okay, I figured out why it does what it does. Very cool.